# Forwarding a subdomain to new port on same IP and Websocket error

Tags: node.js, apache, subdomain, portforwarding

I have a server that I use to run node.js applications. One of which is a messaging app (similar to slack) that we use at my office. When I run the app, the app is reachable at `http://0.0.0.0:8000/` so to reach it externally (from outside the server system) I set up port forwarding using VirtualHost in a conf file. I run the webserver using Apache2.4.18 by the way.
For more details, its running using pm2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I set up the config file like this:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName messenger.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
</VirtualHost>`

The connection works successfully, and I can write to the NoSQL database file just fine, but items dont seem to be getting read from the NoSQL database due to this error

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://messenger.mydomain.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

I don't really have much experience setting up reverse proxies and dealing with WebSockets so after some extensive googling, I'm not exactly sure what I need to get the WebSocket working. I tried learning about like a Ratchet thing for PHP and clank but honestly I'm at a loss. Can anyone provide some direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it.

I needed to run this command `a2enmod rewrite`
PS: make sure you already ran `a2enmod proxy`
`a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`
`a2enmod proxy_http`

Then added to my subdomain.mydomain.com.conf file:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]`

Since I was using port 8000 locally on my server.

This resolved the issue and allows everything to load appropriately.

So my apache2/sites-available/subdomain.mydoamin.com.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.com  

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8000%{REQUEST_URI} [P]  
    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I ran `service apache2 restart`
All was good.